# Online output for dictionary with key within values

Tags: python

How to generate the following output for this dictionary?

Dict:

```
dictBase = {'Name1': {'tbl_1' : 'item1', 'tbl_2' : 'item2'},
            'Name2': {'tbl_1' : 'item1', 'tbl_2' : 'item2'}}
```

Print:

```
Name1, tbl_1, item1, tbl_2, item2
Name2, tbl_1, item1, tbl_2, item2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `str.join` and a loop:

```
for k, v in dictBase.items():
    print(k, *map(', '.join, v.items()), sep=', ')
```

This does rely on the fact that the items are strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that was exactly it

Comment: Are you a doubt, if I wanted to save the output in a variable? Example `for ... var = map ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in dictBase:
  output_line = key
  for subkey in dictBase[key] :
    output_line += ", " + subkey + ", " + dictBase[key][subkey] 
  print (output_line + "/n")
```

If you want to store the whole output in a single variable, as you mention
above, simply do sth like

```
final_output = "";

for key in dictBase:
  output_line = key
  for subkey in dictBase[key] :
    output_line += ", " + subkey + ", " + dictBase[key][subkey] 
  final_output += output_line + "/n" 

print(final_output)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help